# How to prepare a JavaScript value for storage in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Given an unknown JavaScript value, I would like to write it to a property of a Firestore document. But Firestore rejects some values. For example when trying to store the browser's window object, Firestore reports an error:

> #object[FirebaseError FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data.
> Unsupported field value: a custom Window object (found in field data.window in document errors/Ic0sCeKezM1x1kDBI3Hy1)]

The usecase ist to write catched errors to Firestore. But catched errors can be or can contain all kinds of (nested) properties.

So how can I "prepare" an arbitrary value for storage in Firebase? Invalid values could be converted to Strings or just skipped from writing. But the coercion must always succeed.

Comment: I strongly suggest not accepting "arbitrary" data for Firestore documents.  As Frank says below, there are clear data types that Firestore accepts, and you should model your document data using the data types allowed.  If you have a way of serializing your data as a binary blob, you could do that if you want, but Firestore is not really well suiting for making sense of that data for the purpose of queries, and you risk exceeding the max size of a document.

Comment: That is exactly why I am asking for a generic way to coerce arbitrary objects to compatible ones. It makes absolutely no sense to define a schema for a schemaless document storage for storing schemaless documents.

In my opinion there should be a coerce function in the Firebase API where I can pass an arbitrary object and some constraints (max-depth, max-size, converter,...). Since there is no one, I am asking for one. I am sure, thousands of programmers already did this.

Comment: If you want to put entirely unstructured data into a document, that's fine.  You have to provide the mechanism to serialize the data into one of the field value types supported by Firestore.  Firestore isn't a serialization mechansim and it's not a state management for an app's runtime memory - it's just a database.  You just query whatever you put into it, but you have to understand what you're putting into it so that you can compose meaningful queries, and make sense of the query results.

Comment: That is not true. In my program the database needs to store whatever is given. Then the database needs to get it back and the program presents it to a human user. No need for the database or the program to understand the contents. If I needed queries, Firestore would be the last choice. If I needed types, JavaScript would be the last choice.

Comment: Firestore has to understand the contents of the data in order to index it effectively.  Any traditional database would do the same.  For example, it has to be able to distinguish between a string and an number (or any other data type) in order to order that correctly when queried.  If you're just tossing fully unstructured data into it and don't expect it to make judgements about how to index it, then really what you need is a plain key/value store where the actual values are not important at all.  Firestore is not a good key/value store - there are other products that can do that better.

Comment: That said, if you do end up using a key/value store, you would still have to serialze the data somehow.  They will not grab at random javascript objects and try to figure out how to compact them into a single blob of binary data, then reconstitute that on demand.

Answer (score 0):

While Firestore is schemaless, the [list of types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) you can store in it is quite well defined. As you've found, arbitrary objects may not meet these requirements - especially not when they contain methods.

I found it best to not accept arbitrary objects, but actually be explicit about the type of each object I store in Firestore. So for example with a TypeScript definition for each object.

The simplest I found to coerce arbitrary JavaScript objects into Firestore compatible data is by converting them to JSON and back with:

```
const firestoreData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arbitraryObject));
```

Comment: JSON.stringify also fails on a lot of values. A solution which never fails is required. When a nested value is not valid, it should be converted to a string or just skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Pass arbitrary objects through `json-prune` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-prune) before storing them in Firestore.